# Does SonarQube accepts SoapUi test reports?

Tags: automated-testing, soapui, sonarqube

I have an API Java project with somes development tools :

- Maven for build
- Gitlab for CICD
- SonarQube for unit test code coverage and quality code tests (using `sonar-maven-plugin` plugin and `mvn sonar:sonar` command in my CI pipeline)
- Soap UI `.xml` project containing Functional tests

Now, I have to run scheduled functional tests of the SoapUi project, generate a test report and give visibility to the developer.

My question is : Can I send soap test report into SonarQube directly ?
If not, do you have another software to advise me ? Thanks !

Comment: What is the way you use for code coverage assessment by SonarQube?

Comment: @AlexeyR. Yes I updated my question, thks for your attention